# OpenFileDialog in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, openfiledialog

How can I run sth like OpenFileDialog? In ASP.NET there's no this control.

Yes, there's option to use

```
<input type="file" name="filediag" />
```

but there's default name disabled to modifications.

I found either solution

```
<input type="file" name="filediag" style="display:none" />
<input type="button" value="browse..." onclick="document.form1.filediag.click()" />
```

but it doesn't work...or I'm doing sth wrong.

Is there other possibility to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this OpenFileDialog?  In the web world, you usually just select files to upload using a FileUpload control. Web sites are quite a bit different than desktop applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have missed the [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control - this is the equivalent to the HTML `input type="file"` used for uploading files.

It exposes the uploaded file - name and contents.

Comment: And here is a pretty good article talking about using the FileUpload control - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

Comment: Is there possibility change name of the button?

Comment: @Saint_pl - no. This is how the _browser_ renders the control and can't be easily changed. You can search SO for "style file input" for some creative solutions.

Comment: @Saint_pl: If you want a slicker upload user experience you'll need to ditch the FileUpload control and move to an Ajax-based upload control. See http://www.uploadify.com/ for an example.